# Using ANOVA on parameter values which are converted in percentages

Tags: anova

I am wondering if you can use ANOVA with data converted in percentages.

When working with cellculture in biology, you have a 3 test rule: 3 independent tests should each show the same result - at the end you evaluate all 3 tests together with a ANOVA + posthoc test. As the inter-test variability is quite high in cellculture experiments (age of cellline, age of chemicals used (fresh or 24h old etc.)) it is common to convert the measured parameters into percentages and perform the ANOVA with the percentage values.

My english is not the best and I will use an example to clarify my question: 
E.g. I test if substance A can produce a certain response, luminal units (LU), in a cellculture. So I have a control (only the solvent), a positive control and, substance A in 3 concentracions. I measure the parameter (LU) and set the parameter value of the control to 100% and convert the values of the other substances/positive control based on the 100% of the control. I do this for each of the 3 tests independentley. Based on the percentage values of all three tests I perform an ANOVA with a posthoc test; so I have 3 percentage values for every substance/control etc.

Is this, from a statistical point of view, a correct way to handle the data? The majority of publications uses this way to handle the data, however I am not convinced that you can handle the data in that way. E.g. the variability of the control is neglected completley as the control is always set to 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has a similar question:

The right answer is: No, you cannot use ANOVA, but you have to use a paired t-test. Anova is not suitable because the normality and homogeneity assumptions are not met. However, with a paired t-test the difference between DMSO and the tested substance does meet the normality and homogeneity assumptions. So a paired t-test with DMSO + tested substance for all 3 tests is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that

> the variability of the control is neglected completley as the control
>   is always set to 100%

But, if I understood you correctly, you do not compare control group to other groups. You just compare responses from 3 tests and these responses are expressed in "% of control" units.

If yes, you can do ANOVA (assuming normality an homogeneity of variance assumptions are met). But you have to be carefull when drawing conclusions. Large p-value doesn't mean that tests do not differ significantly, it means that your tests do not differ significantly **relative to their controls**. But this is not a problem if you can assume that controls do not differ significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. One question: "you do not compare control group to other groups" - most of the time I am interested in the difference betwen control and "other group". Because if there is a difference it shows that my substance has an effect - thats the thing I want to know - effect: yes or no. 

Controls do not differ significantly, just slightly. So I can use ANOVA and need to be just a little bit careful regarding the evaluation of the p-value?!

Comment: You wrote "at the end you evaluate all 3 tests together with a ANOVA + posthoc test"

Comment: Yes, but I do not really see your point.
The Datamatrix looks like this:

Control: 3 times 100%

Positive Control: % of control units test 1, % of control units test 2 and % of control units test 3.

Substance A: % of control units test 1, % of control units test 2 and % of control units test 3.

Substance B: % of control units test 1, % of control units test 2 and % of control units test 3.

etc. 

And with Controls + Substances tested I do the ANOVA and posthoc test.

Comment: Now I see. But why you inclde Controls in ANOVA? I thought you wish to compare Substance A response in test1, test 2 and test 3.

Comment: Oh no you missunderstood that part. I wish to compare Substance A response with the Control response. However, in cell culture it is common practice (GSP = good scientific practice) to show results based on 3 independent experiments/tests. So I want to compare the response from Substance A and Control based on three tests. What is done in literature very often is an ANOVA including the percentage values of each test

Comment: OK, so I'd say it's simply matter of unit you use. Here you have "% of constrol" instead of ml or mg or whatever you could use. But one thing is strange: if you have only 100's in Control group, how could ANOVA assumptions (normality + homogeneity of variance) be met?

Comment: Actually this is a good question... I just followed the normal literature and at some point I was not sure if the literature does it right. Apparently not.